# How far can one go in creating new words?

Tags: prefixes, neologisms, negative-prefixes

Apparently the word ***disturbingly*** exists, but ***undisturbingly*** doesn't. However, I felt it better served to convey my meaning and was sure that any reader would understand what I mean. I also put it between inverted commas to indicate that I voluntarily used a non-existent word.

Is there a limit to creating such words in language that is *not literature*?

Comment: What do you mean, non-existent? It won't be in dictionaries, because *un-* is a productive prefix and you won't find every *un-* word listed at all, especially if the meaning is obvious.

Comment: It depends on your intentions, and whether you are bothered about how your writing will be received. Between two young children, made-up words, signs, and codes are of course fine. Writing for an editor or to satisfy the requirements of an institution, it would be wrong not to go with their views (or change editor, etc).  Writing a novel, you're again free to write even gibberish if you like. But serious writers will obey Grice's wise maxims (don't be unclear, etc) and Orwell's 'sixth' (avoid the grotesque). I'd say scare quotes around 'undisturbingly' are worse than none in running text....

Comment: _But asking "Is 'undisturbingly' a word?" on ELU_ would lead to different opinions, back to the old issue of _What constitutes wordness?_, and would in my opinion be off-topic. _But have you checked in OED?_

Comment: So in a publication that is not literature, you can use words that are not in the dictionary, without these 'scare quotes'? I am not asking if 'undisturbingly' is a word. As i type it, the English corrector underlines it with red which makes me smile. This is not only about this particular word. I was curious if there are any guidelines in creating new words in a non-fictional text.

Comment: An odd word calls attention to itself. I'd use that pause as judiciously as a spice. More than one odd word a page and I'm overseasoning the work and slowing the reader. Then I'd question whether I want that effect or not.

Comment: @ Yosef: I totally agree. This is another criterion, I am so pleased! I got three until now and one little one about punctuation.There a few words, even among the existing ones, that must be used only once on a page, in a chapter and even in a whole book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find in a dictionary such as the SOED that several hundreds of words created by addition of the prefix "-un" are not listed in the dictionary as regular entries, but instead under the entry for this prefix; only a few are defined but all that are found in that entry are in it because they have appeared in print; a date of earliest recording is included for each. This means that all those instances have been considered acceptable by lexicographers. You do not find "undisturbingly" in this list and that means that possibly it does  exist as an already used term and that it has been rejected, although I doubt very much that this should be the case: it's probable that it  does not exist as an already used term and therefore it certainly doesn't either as accepted by the lexicographers. Given the plausibility of the concept you are therefore quite justified in coining this term. There are limits in this domain of the productive constructions with "-un", as with other affixes and combining forms. All such constructions do not necessarily result in a word of sufficient plausibility; let's take for instance the concept embodied in the adjective "live" as it pertains to events (live events, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+events&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20events%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clive%20events%3B%2Cc0)). If we do not take into account this criterion of plausibility, which I believe motivates lexicographers in their decision, it seems that we are justified in speaking of "unlive events"; yet the plausibility of referring to representations as events in general does not appear likely and therefore "unlive event" does not appear to be a reality of our world, which precludes the existence of an adjective "unlive"; so, productivity and creation stop here.

Common sense tells us that the only limit not to indulge in, not only in literature but in all domain of verbal expression, is the creation of terms for a concept that has been properly named already, this being done without showing that the new appellation has any advantage over the existing one, except that of providing a synonym (it is sometimes considered that a synonym is useful but the question of synonymy has no clear cut answer).

Comment: Definitely happy with your answer. The criterion of PLAUSIBILITY and of already existing words for the meaning we want to convey are very reasonable and helpful guidelines! pity I can give only one Up Vote :)

Comment: In fact *undisturbing* is listed in OED (and *-ly* is a productive suffix); and *undisturbedly* is listed in its own right.

Comment: ' "[U]nlive event" does not appear to be a reality of our world' would mean that "live event" was nonsensical tautology. This "live" means "screened (etc) in real time", a broadened usage, so "unlive" would be productively reasonable. However, "nonlive" is already attested by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonlive#:~:text=non%2D%20%2B%E2%80%8E%20live-,Adjective,a%20nonlive%20vaccine%20nonlive%20music) (in various senses, including the "nonlive music" sense).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In a way, yes, "live event" is tautological, redondant; defining "live" as "not a product of  modifications through removal and addition of clips", any representation not satisfying to this criterion is not the representation  of an event, not an event, speaking loosely; (essential in the idea of event is continuity, even though there might periods of relatively negligible activity depending on the event); then there is no real possibility of speaking of a nonlive event.